# How to turn on the Scheduled Task Agent after it is off by battery saver in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, scheduled-tasks

I have added Scheduled Task Agent in my WP7 app to remind the periodically. While testing after 2-3 days the agent will be off and it won't turn back again even if i open the app and start the task again.
Below is what I have tried in my ScheduledTaskAgent:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        if (time.Hour > 6 && time.Hour < 23)
        {
            getContent();
            if (task.Name.Equals("PeriodicTaskDemo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
                Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "ScheduledAgentData");
                mutex.WaitOne();
                IsolatedStorageSettings setting = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
                toast.Title = setting["ScheduledAgentData"].ToString();
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                toast.Content = "You are being notified!!";
                toast.Show();
            }
            NotifyComplete();
        }

    }
```

Comment: from overview of background agents in msdn:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx :Battery Saver mode is an option that the user can enable on the device to indicate that battery life should be prioritized. If this mode is enabled, periodic agents may not run, even if the interval has elapsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The battery saver won't disable you background task from starting again. The only reasons your agent was disabled:

- you have disabled it manually in background tasks settings
- it crashed in exception two times in a row
- it exceeded the maximum running time several times in a row (~20s)
- it has used more memory than it was available (6MB memory cap on WP7, 11MB on WP8)
- when scheduling task, you also set the property for how long it should run, after this time it won't start again. On WP7 background tasks stops running after 14 days automatically.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your useful information. I think the fifth one is what I want to know. How can we set the property of the schedule task to run for a given no. of days?

Comment: When creating the PeriodicAgent class, there is property Expiration time. I usually set the upper limit using this: ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14),